# How to get a specific element in a collection field of a JPA entity?

Tags: spring-data-jpa, hibernate-criteria, criteria-api

I'm using Criteria API to retrieve entities from the database. I have two entities as following:

```
public class EntityA {
    String primaryKey;
    @JoinColumn(
       updatable = false, 
       insertable = false, 
       name = "primaryKey", 
       referencedColumnName = "primaryKeyOne")
    List<EntityB> list;
}
public class EntityB {
    String primaryKeyOne;
    String primaryKeyTwo;
    String name;
    Integer value;
}
```

Now I want to create a Spring JPA `Specification` using these two entities.

```
public interface Specification<T> {
    Predicate toPredicate(Root<T> root, CriteriaQuery<?> cr, CriteriaBuilder cb);
}
```

After I fetched `EntityA`, I can get the whole list of `EntityB`. But how do I filter out a specific instance of `EntityB` and create a `predicate` using it? My intention is as the following:

```
cb.gt(root.get("list").stream().filter(e -> "abc".equals(e.getName())).get("value"), 100)
```

Answer (score 0):

Usually you should perform a join between the two entities and do the filtering based on the `join`.

Given your example, the specification will be something like the following:

```
public class EntityASpecifications {

    public static Specification<EntityA> toSpecification(String name, Integer value){
        return (root, criteriaQuery, criteriaBuilder) -> {
            Join<EntityA, EntityB> entityBJoin = root.join("list");

            return criteriaBuilder.and(
                    criteriaBuilder.equal(entityBJoin.get("name"), name),
                    criteriaBuilder.gt(entityBJoin.get("value"), value)
            );
        };
    }

}
```

You will then use it with the repository of EntityA like so,

```
entityARepository.findAll(EntityASpecifications.toSpecification("abc", 100));
```